# zsh syntax highlighter : Make corresponding parenthesis blink

Tags: zsh, iterm2, zsh-syntax-highlighting

I'm using the [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting) on MacOS (with iTerm2) and wonder whether I can configure it so that, if the cursor is on a parenthesis, the corresponding matching parenthesis on the command line would be shown as blinking.

I tried the setting

```
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[cursor-matchingbracket]='fg=red,standout'
```

In the iTerm2 preferences for my terminal profile, section Text, I placed a checkmark on "Blinking text".

I would expect the matching bracket to show in red foreground, blinking.

However the correspondent bracket is shown with red **background** and no blinking.